# Smoke domain glitches Blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, artifacts

Why does this happen? This is from an old render - sometimes there’s no weird glitching, but on other projects, the moment I press render animation, I get weird frames where the smoke domain just randomly fills the domain box. It’s fine on other frames and renders as normal. I have messed around with light paths and follow best practices when setting up the domain. What’s causing this?
[image]

Comment: Did you bake the smoke simulation before rendering? And please use proper screenshots instead of taking pictures of your monitor.

Comment: Yes, I did bake the simulation & this is a screenshot - the colour banding is the result of post processing & the extreme chromatic abberstion may give you that impression - apologies!